# Docker compose refuses to apply environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**UPDATE**
It appears the problem is specifically related to the RUN command in the Dockerfile. If I remove it, the build works fine and the environment variables are clearly being picked up since the password gets applied and I can connect using it. Not sure why the login fails in the RUN command, I've seen many examples using similar code.

I'm working on a very basic docker compose file to setup a dev environment for an app and I started with the database server, which is MS SQL. Here's what the docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mssql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mssql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '1434:1433'
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
    volumes:
      - mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql
```

As you can see from my dockerfile path, that's in a sub-path and looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

COPY ./docker/mssql/TESTDB.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/TESTDB.bak

RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U SA -P "YourStrong!Passw0rd" -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE TESTDB FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/TESTDB.bak" WITH MOVE "TESTDB_Data" to "/var/opt/mssql/data/TESTDB.mdf", MOVE "TESTDB_Log" to "/var/opt/mssql/data/TESTDB_log.ldf"'
```

(Yes, I realize that the password in the RUN command is redundant, I had tried to use a variable there earlier and since it wasn't working I hard coded it.)

When I run *docker-compose up -d*, I always get this error: *Login failed for user 'SA'*

I wasted way too much time thinking there was actually something wrong with the password until I realized that if I add the environment variables directly in the Dockerfile, it works. So in my Dockerfile, above the RUN command, I can just do this:

```
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd
```

So I concluded that my environment variables simply aren't being read. I tried with quotes, without quotes, using *env_file* instead, nothing seems to work. I also tried the following format, no luck:

```
environment
  - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
  - SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd
```

I also tried using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead of SA_PASSWORD, as well as having both in there. I assumed that was unlikely to be the problem though given SA_PASSWORD works fine. Lastly, I tried using a 2017 image in case it was image specific, that didn't work either.

I'm assuming it must be something silly I'm missing. I saw a lot of talk of .env in the root being different, but if I understood correctly people go wrong with that when they try to use environment values in their docker-compose.yml file, which is not what I'm doing here. So I'm about ready to lose my mind on this as it seems like such a simple, basic thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing the ENV statement in Dockerfile with the environment variables set when *running* an image. The key is still in the details of the docs. It notes that they are the same as saying docker *run* -e, not docker build.

What's causing more confusion, when you use ENV, you are setting defaults for when the image runs later:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

If you haven't yet, I very much recommend getting familiar with building and running your image with docker run and docker build before moving on to compose, it's much less confusing that way.

Comment: I believe it’s the first format I tried and it didn’t work either. I’ll try it again tomorrow just to make sure.

Comment: It's not. Look at your volumes section, I assume it's working right? Volumes is a list of strings in the same format you would pass to -v. Environment is a list of strings in the format you would pass to -e.

Comment: I just meant I tried the format you mention too and it hadn't worked.  tried it again this  morning to confirm it didn't fix the problem. I've updated my answer with some additional things I tried (different image, using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD).

Comment: Oh, I think I see your confusion with the updates. ENV in a Dockerfile is a variable used while *building* with docker build. The environment variables being passed in by docker-compose are there when running the image that's been built. The key thing is still that step in the docs, they are passed into *docker run -e* not to docker build.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I ended up figuring it out. I had read the docs and I thought I had understood them, but turns out there was another layer to it that I got confused.  have now updated to use build > args in the docker compose file and then created a .env file in my root to populate that. I can then access the args values in the Dockerfile, everything works fine. So turns out my subject was wrong and the environment variables are working fine. Your answers were the most precise so I awarded you the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer is not correct. The `environment` property accepts variables in an array syntax as well as in a map syntax, see [the compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment).

Comment: Ah yes, I had to test twice but I believe you are correct. Their answer was probably *only* the build part. I believe the environment variables don't get passed to the build step in compose.

Answer (score 1):

Both responses above are fine, just a few more things:

SA_PASSWORD **is deprecated** instead use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD

It is always nice to define .env files with the variables for instance:

**sapassword.env**

```
MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd
```

**sqlserver.env**

```
ACCEPT_EULA=Y
MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/data
MSSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/log
MSSQL_BACKUP_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/backup
```

**And in docker-compose.yml instance the env files the following way:**

```
environment:
      - sqlserver.env
      - sapassword.env
```

Comment: @jvmcollaborator Wouldn't you use env_file for that instead of environment? I did try that, as a matter of fact it was my preference, I moved to environment after env_file failed to work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your build here stems from a confusion between the *build-time* and *run-time* environment variables: with the [`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) or [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) properties you specify the environment variables to be set for the service *container*.

But the `RUN` command in your `Dockerfile` is executed at the build-time of the *image*! To pass variables when building a new image you should use build [`args`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#args) instead, as you already mentioned [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299665/docker-compose-refuses-to-apply-environment-variables#comment129474632_73299910):

```yaml
services:
  mssql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mssql/Dockerfile
      args:
        SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
    # ...
```

With this you can use the `SA_PASSWORD` as a build `ARG`:

```docker
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

COPY ./docker/mssql/TESTDB.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/TESTDB.bak

ARG SA_PASSWORD
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U SA -P "$SA_PASSWORD" -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE TESTDB FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/TESTDB.bak" WITH MOVE "TESTDB_Data" to "/var/opt/mssql/data/TESTDB.mdf", MOVE "TESTDB_Log" to "/var/opt/mssql/data/TESTDB_log.ldf"'
```

---

If you want to move the actual password to a `.env` file you can use [variable substitution in the `compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files):

```yaml
services:
  mssql:
    build:
      # ...
      args:
        SA_PASSWORD: "$SA_PASSWORD"
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yml, have you tried:

```
  - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
  - SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd
```

Comment: I believe it’s the first format I tried and it didn’t work either. I’ll try it again tomorrow just to make sure.

Comment: I've confirmed that this doesn't fix it for me.